# Why you can I use FileVault without CD, USB, floppy etc. for system start/rescue, but not BitLocker or VeraCrypt?

Tags: disk-encryption, bitlocker, veracrypt, filevault

I have encrypted my harddrive on mac with FileVault. I can start my system with password only. To recover the system I had to store a rescue password for example as a picture.

With BitLocker (without TPM) there is a USB needed for every start of the system.

VeraCrypt also needs a CD/DVD for system recovery.

My question is - why there is such a difference?

*Update*

For me it is easier to use some full disk encryption without extra CD, USB etc needed for every start of the system. For the password recovery purpose I would prefer some information that could be written down on a normal piece of paper or stored as a picture.

Comment: "without extra CD, USB etc needed for every start of the system" what do you mean by that? TrueCrypt only needs the CD when you create the encrypted harddisk, not for booting (except when you actually need to recover the header after the original one got corrupted) I'd expect VeraCrypt to work the same way.

Comment: @CodesInChaos if I create a hard drive encryption with bitlocker without TPM I need to use USB for every start of the system.

Comment: @CodesInChaos at least thats was how I understood the bitlocker :)

Comment: That sounds like a weak form of two-factor-auth, similar to the key files TrueCrypt supports and not like a rescue disk. Completely different feature.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have edited my question. Is it now easier to understand? :)